# PowerShell window preventing shutdown

Tags: windows-server-2003, powershell

If I have a PowerShell window (at the PowerShell command prompt) on display it prevents the computer shutting down.

I.e. if I open a PowerShell window and then try to shutdown the server, I get the End Program popup saying Windows cannot end this program.

I get the same result if I start PowerShell from the start menu, from a cmd prompt and from a shortcut with -NoExit specified.

How can I get shutdown to automatically close a PowerShell window (if it is at the PowerShell prompt) in the same way as it would for a CMD window?

Alternatively, is it possible for PowerShell to detect when a shutdown has been initiated and therefore close itself?

Going down the alternative route as suggested by pk, I have come up with this test code:

```
Write-Host "PowerShellBlockingShutdown.ps1 Started"

$global:shuttingDown = $false
$sysevent = [microsoft.win32.systemevents]
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $sysevent -EventName "SessionEnding" -Action {$global:shuttingDown = $true; Write-Host "  SessionEnding"}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $sysevent -EventName "SessionEnded"  -Action {$global:shuttingDown = $true; Write-Host "  SessionEnded"}

do {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
    if ($global:shuttingDown) {break}
    Write-Host "  Waiting for Shutdown"
} while ($true)

Write-Host "PowerShellBlockingShutdown.ps1 Finished"
```

Which seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm blatantly cut/pasting this answer from another [site](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/ITCG/thread/760a3afb-70dc-48f6-810a-fc1d85fe43c1) (since linking is frowned upon and I don't have a better answer).  I do believe this will resolve your problem.

> ...it looks like you can set up a Event watcher using
>   Register-ObjectEvent using `[microsoft.win32.systemevents]` and watching
>   for either `SessionEnding` or `SessionEnded`.  I haven't had time to test
>   this out, but you could look at using something like this:

```
$sysevent = [microsoft.win32.systemevents]
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $sysevent -EventName "SessionEnding" -Action {"Shutdown/Logoff detected.";Get-Process -Name Powershell | Stop-Process -Force}
```

> More information about this class can be found here:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents_events.aspx

Comment: Cheers. I saw that and was wondering what it all meant :-) I'll have a play and get back to you

Comment: I've added my solution to the question